# Console error: Uncaught ReferenceError: gsap is not defined

Tags: javascript, console, gsap

Please help with console error: Uncaught ReferenceError: gsap is not defined
I include GSAP with cdn by:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.8.0/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.min.js"></script>
```

And using it in js file:

```
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
gsap.to('.laptop__top', {
scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: '.laptop',
    start: '20px top',
    end: '250px top',
    // markers: true,
    scrub: 2.5,
},
rotationX: 0,
duration: 5,
```

});

But anywhere get error.

Comment: It shouldn't be undefined with the scripts in that order (I just checked in a stack snippet). It sounds like some other error (a 404? 500?) has occurred and this is a follow-on from that.

Comment: Make sure the first script is actually loaded properly.

Comment: Add a defer to your script tag <script src = "" defer></script>

Comment: Make sure to also load ScrollTrigger before your script that uses it.

Comment: kindly put your code inside "document ready" function

Answer (score 1):

Add this CDN below your current Gsap CDN

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.5/ScrollTrigger.min.js (make sure the CDN versions are the same)

**Ref:** https://gsap.com/docs/v3/Installation